# Benchmark a real-time planning algorithm using Optaplanner

Tags: benchmarking, optaplanner

I'm trying to benchmark a real-time planning algorithm but can't seem to find how to do it, is this supported in Optaplanner?

I've successfully run a benchmark using an offline version of my problem. I've implemented `SolutionFileIO` that reads my problem instances and converts them to a solution. I've read the docs and saw the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpcPEieU3Cg&list=PLJY69IMbAdq0uKPnjtWXZ2x7KE1eWg3ns&index=7) related to benchmarking but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Alternatively, I can run the real-time algorithms using my own framework, but that would require me to manually define all Optaplanner heuristics that I want to run (which is quite cumbersome when using a matrix setup). Is there a way to instantiate the solvers (in Java) based on the benchmark xml definition? This would allow me to run my own real-time benchmark while still using the Optaplanner benchmark definition.

Comment: With real-time planning, can we assume you mean that you're firing `ProblemFactChange`s at it?

Comment: I actually didn't implement it using `ProblemFactChange` (but could've done so). Upon problem change, I'm stopping the algorithm and starting it with the new problem definition including latest best schedule. So essentially it is a warm restart.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `ProblemFactChange` as that's potentially more efficient/faster. Any reason why you're not?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, thanks. I'm not (yet) doing that because the current setup requires less implementation, my simulator [RinSim](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/) already gathers all necessary information. If this setup isn't fast enough I will definitely consider using `ProblemFactChange`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A benchmark config that also fires `ProblemFactChange` events (= real-time planning), is not yet supported, [vote for this jira](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-501). *How would you like the benchmark config to look like?*

To HACK reusing the solvers from a benchmark configuration, cast `PlannerBenchmark` to `PlannerBenchmarkRunner` and use `getPlannerBenchmarkResult().getSolverBenchmarkResultList()`, but that will give up on a bunch of orchestration (including the report). Instead, if you can succeed in overriding `SubSingleBenchmarkResult`, you wouldn't loose that orchestration (but your hacks would be even deeper).

Whatever you end up doing, do share how you'd the benchmark config to look like, as this will give us inspiration when we implement it for a future OptaPlanner version.

Comment: I've just tried the first hack that you described and it seems to work:
`final SolverConfig configFromBenchmark = .. //using code above` then creating an empty factory: `final SolverFactory factory = SolverFactory.createEmpty();`, adding the config:    `factory.getSolverConfig().inherit(configFromBenchmark);` and creating a solver instance using `factory.buildSolver();`